react native screen not taking full height and children flex items not evenly spaced
In my Screen component I am trying to have the container that holds the Card components from react-native-paper be full height of the remaining spaces, but as you can see in the screen shot, the conatiner that holds the cards (yellow bg) is not full height and that is also squeezing the flex items (the cards).
How can I make it so that the container (yellow bg) is full height of remaining space and also have the flex items evenly spaced out?
I tried flex: 1 and also height: '100%', but it does not work

// Screen component

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: 'black', height: '100%', flex: 1 }}>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
        backgroundColor={backgroundStyle.backgroundColor}
      />
      <ScrollView
        style={{backgroundColor: 'pink', height: '100%', flex: 1 }}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'yellow',
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'space-evenly',,
            height: '100%'
          }}>
            {surveyData?.surveys?.map((surveyDetails, i) => (
              <Card key={`suvey-card-${i}`} style={{flex: 1, flexGrow: 1}>
                <Card.Title
                  title={surveyDetails.name}
                  right={(props) => <Icon {...props} source="folder" />}
                />
              </Card>
            ))}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );


The reason you are not seeing the ScrollView take the full space with flex: 1 is because the ScrollView component actually has a container wrapped around it. If you want the ScrollView to occupy the entire space you can add styles to the container like this:
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }} style={{...

However I would not recommend this unless you have a specific reason to do so. If you're looking at add spacing between each item then you can add a gap to your item container like so:
<View style={{
  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  flex: 1,
  gap: 6,
  justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
}}>
...


I just found out about the contentContainerStyle prop, and it fixed the issue for me, but why dont you recommend this specifically?

@henhen it could cause spacing issues with the sibling elements, and it could keep you from scrolling to items off screen if your list is long enough.
